# Ошибка в python: ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Люди добрые, помогите исправить ошибку!

> File "", line 8, in  ValueError: math domain error

Фрагмент кода:

```
from math import sqrt
p = input("Введите x (ax2+bx+c) :")
a = float (input("Введите число :"))
b = float (input("Введите число :"))
c = float( input("Введите число :"))
D = b*2 - 4*a*c
print(D)
x1 = -b - sqrt(D)/2*a
x2 = -b + sqrt(D)/2*a
print(x1)
print(x2)
```

Comment: math domain error - буквально "ошибка из области математики". Скорее всего вы задали параметры при которых D отрицательный (проверку на отрицательный дискриминант кто будет делать?)

Comment: Было бы очень полезно, если бы Вы сказали, что выводит `print(D)`

Comment: надо искать x не в переменых а в print

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в восьмой строке. Именно там вычисляется квадратный корень из дискриминанта, неотрицательность которого не была проверена. Очевидно, это и приводит к ошибке, т.к. классический `sqrt` из модуля `math` не работает с комплексными числами.

Простейшим решением будет переписать Ваш код так:

```py
from math import sqrt
p = input("Введите x (ax2+bx+c) :")
a = float (input("Введите число :"))
b = float (input("Введите число :"))
c = float( input("Введите число :"))
D = b*2 - 4*a*c
print(D)

assert(D >= 0)

x1 = -b - sqrt(D)/2*a
x2 = -b + sqrt(D)/2*a
print(x1)
print(x2)
```

`assert()` проверяет условие в скобках и, если оно ложно, вызывает исключение `AssertionError`.

Если же работа с комплексными числами всё же входит в Ваши планы, решение будет ещё более простым: замените модуль `math` на `cmath`. Этот модуль также содержит функцию `sqrt`, однако поддерживает работу с комплексными числами.